# How to convert multi-page WordPress theme to single-page theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Actually i'm having a multi-page WordPress theme. But I don't want a multi-page website. I want all my contents are in a single page like, when I click a nav button (say "contact us"), it should scroll down to the bottom of the page. And I want the same theme should be formatted into a single page website. Any help/trick would be appreciated!

Thanks and Regards
sharfudeen.

Comment: You can use single page paid and free themes which can have same functionality that you want

Comment: But I don't want another theme. I just wanted to edit my existing theme itself. Anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create custom menu for one page website

```
 Appearance -> Menus -> Custom Links
```

like Menu name "About" and Url "http://xyx.com/#about"

then set the id of particular section like

Note : url #about and id="about" both must same

```
<section id="about">
about us content
</section>
```

Comment: Let me try than!

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this link it helps you.

[scrolling script](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)